# How do i interpret inline javascript code in python on GAE?

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

I'm in use python based on GAE (Google App Engine) and want to interpret inline javascript code.

like as a SpiderMonkey(https://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey),

> from spidermonkey import Runtime
>   rt = Runtime()
>   cx = rt.new_context()
>   cx.eval_script("1 + 2") + 3
>
> class Foo:
>
> > def hello(self):
> >     print "Hello, Javascript world!"
>
> cx.bind_class(Foo, bind_constructor=True)
>   cx.eval_script("var f = new Foo(); f.hello();")
>   f = cx.eval_script("f;")
>   f.hello()
>
> # Hello, Javascript world!

how can i do it? or Is it possible to install a spidermonkey on GAE?

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Why do you need to interpret JS in the app backend?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use it in appengine.  If you look at the installation docs it says

"At present, you'll need a C compiler on your system to install this extension, as well as the Pyrex package."

This sort of thing is not supported on appengine in the python SDK.  It can only have dependencies on supported 3rd party libraries and pure python code that you supply.

Have a read of the python runtime on appengine docs

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_The_sandbox

and the 3rd party libs docs

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Oh and this sort of question has been asked hundreds of times here.  Whilst not specific to the library in question SpiderMonkey, all ask the same thing, so some searching in SO might save you some time.

Comment: Thanks. I've expected that it cannot be installed on GAE. my actual question is how do i interpret javascript code that inserted as a inline code in python.

Comment: You can't due to the reasons stated, unless you can find a pure python javascript interpreter or you switch to java and use Rhino.